# using IF statements to add together prices using VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am trying to use if statements to add the prices of a cruises special packages together. I am using check boxes for the packages, so any, from none to all 3 are able to be checked. The packages available are VIP, excursion and restaurant. The price will also depend on the cruise length (7 or 10 day). I am wondering on which format to use, and if I even need to use if statements, but this one has me stumped. If anyone has any ideas on how to make this statement true, I'd appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a common event handler for your CheckBox's to call an update method like this.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    UpdatePricing()
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UpdatePricing()
    Dim total As Double
    Dim pricing1 As Double = 2000.99
    Dim pricing2 As Double = 4000.49
    Dim pricing3 As Double = 6000.19

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then total = total + pricing1
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then total = total + pricing2
    If CheckBox3.Checked Then total = total + pricing3 


    Label1.Text = Format(total, "$####0.00")
End Sub
```