# VB: Using IF statements to add together variables in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

This program I am working on is to determine the price of a Cruise. There is a basic cruise charge (7 or 10 day), plus variables costs that include different cruise packages. There are a total of 3 packages, and any combinations of packages can be selected from none, to all 3. I am trying to create an if block that will (a) tell me whether the user has selected a 7 or 10 day cruise, (b) determine the prices of those packages, and add them to a total number, and (c) print the packages by their first initial (V, E, R) on the next line of the listbox. My program so far is as follows.

```
If chkVIP.Checked Then
            strPackageInfo = strPackageInfo + "V"
            If optSeven.Checked Then
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 100
            Else
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 150
            End If
        End If
        If chkExcursion.Checked Then
            strPackageInfo = strPackageInfo + "E"
            If optSeven.Checked Then
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 200
            Else
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 300
            End If
        End If
        If chkRestaurant.Checked Then
            strPackageInfo = strPackageInfo + "R"
            If optSeven.Checked Then
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 70
            Else
                dblTotal = dblTotal + 100
            End If
  End If
```

I need to use something around the likes of:

lstInvoice.Items.Add(String.Format(strFormat, "Cruise package charge", FormatCurrency(dblTotal)))

to show my answer in the listbox. I am unsure where to place this line of code, however.

In advance thank you very much for your assistance on this matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using IF statements to add together prices using VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049816/using-if-statements-to-add-together-prices-using-vb)

Comment: Its a different question, but its the same area. I've already figured out that area, now I need to figure out this one.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, first you should validate data, then evaluate your business logic, then do presentation.

So, first validate your input data, then determine the package info and calculate the cost. Then, once all your business logic is complete, insert the line item(s) into the invoice.

Also, your example is missing an "End If" (in the restaurant block).